# Hot to generate the correct URL if hardcoded in Symfony project?

Tags: symfony, router

When I use the function {{ path('contact_route') }} and its equivalent in controller the generated URL is correct => http://localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php/contact.

But if I hardcode the URL (I am forced to do so in some particular cases), I get something unwanted, (a href="/contact") => http://localhost/contact

Comment: I think the right question is why you have to hardcode the URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are "probably" asking is how to prepend the correct base URL to your manual built URL, i.e. something like this:

```
a href="{{ app.request.baseUrl }}/contact"
```

or if you need the FQDN URL:

```
a href="{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() }}/contact"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you expect if you set `<a href="/contact">...`, it's nothing more that relative url which point to the referring page plus '/contact'.