# Load images in PDF without a bundle - Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, pdf

I'm confronted in integrating a pdf to my project with some css.
But there it comes that I need to actually add an image.

I saw that there is `KnpSnappyBundle` available, but my css actually works without it as I can add colors and everything. My only question is how can I add an image without using any bundle ?

I tried with a twig link in the html like this

```
<img class="logo" src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}">
```

I tried with an absolute path like this

```
<img class="logo" src="{{ asset('images/logo.png', absolute = true) }}">
```

I tried to add it in the css too:

```
.logo {
        background: url('images/logo.png');
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }
```

the pdf opens but there is no logo.

So does anyone have an idea on how to do it?

Comment: you might need to check this before wasting too much time on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833222/adding-external-images-to-pdf-using-itext and https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1337846

Comment: Now the question is do you want to generate pdf with embeded images , if yes you have domain naming issue

Comment: @sakhunzai hi, hm so there is no way i could do that without a bundle? seems that im in the wrong way right?

Comment: its obvious you need  `KnpSnappyBundle` to generate a pdf

Answer (score 0):

The usual problem with  Snappy package which internally uses `wkhtmltopdf`
tool, is domain name referencing. You should convert all your relative resource paths to absolute paths , and it will work for you. You should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32258236/hot-to-generate-the-correct-url-if-hardcoded-in-symfony-project#32272662) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049712/how-to-use-absolute-path-in-twig-functions) to convert all css/image links

Comment: thanks for the help. I do not need anything on links, or maybe should I? I wanted to just display the company logo, but seems that it is really hard to do that. + i'm not using any bundle for that

Comment: Would you mind adding detail on how you are generating a pdf ?